# アクセス数をもとに人気の記事を取得するには

Tags: ruby-on-rails

勉強のため`rails`+`mysql`でブログを作っています。
人気の記事一覧というものを表示したいのですが、設計についてアドバイスください。

### 機能

ログを元に

- 日毎
- 週ごと
- 月ごと
- 年ごと
- トータル

の人気記事をランキング化して取得

### ログの取り方

アクセスがあるたびにログ用のテーブルに保存

= 気になること・わからないこと =

単純にアクセスがあるたびに記録してしまうと、同じユーザがリロードするだけで人気記事になってしまうので、対策をとりたい。

### ログの保存の仕方

ログ用のテーブルを作って、アクセスログとして記録。

= 気になること・わからないこと =

どの程度の規模まで耐えられるか。
1アクセスごとに1データ挿入されるので、肥大化した際の影響がきになる。

もっと適した方法はないか。

### 集計の仕方

上記のログを元に、指定した期間のログの中でもっともログの多かった記事を計算。

= 気になること・わからないこと =

過去のランキングは再計算する必要がないので、計算結果を記録するべきか。
その際に気をつけることはあるか。

### ログ用のテーブル設計

- id
- post_id
- created_at

---

以上です。
未熟な部分があると思いますが、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リレーショナルDB(mydql)は、ログ系のデータを管理するのは苦手です。最近は、アクセスログをfluentd 経由でkibanaやmongodbなどに送って解析するというのが流行りです。とは言え、mysqlだけでも出来なくはないので、注意点を書いておきたいと思います。

- ログの取り方について
  リロードによる再カウントを防ぐためには、ユーザごとにユニークなIDを生成してcookieに埋め込めば大丈夫です。アクセスログには、cookieのIDを記録します。同じIDのアクセスは、解析時に一つにまとめます。
- ログの保存の仕方
  定期的に古いデータを削除するようにしないと、解析も遅くなりますし、容量も無駄に消費します。定期的に削除するとして、SQLのDELETEだと結構重くなるので、日付をキーにしてパーティションを区切るというようなことを行うことが多いです。パーティションの削除(DROP)は、高速に動作します。
- 集計の仕方
  日毎・月毎の集計サマリーを別テーブルに作って保存すると良いと思います。サマリーの作成はバッチで行います。アクセスログを別のDB(mongodb)などに保存する場合でも、サマリーはmysqlで保存します。すべての記事の日別アクセス数を保存しておき、月別サマリーは日別サマリーを合計、年別サマリーは月別サマリーを合計すればよいでしょう。サマリーを計算後は、アクセスログを削除します。

参考になりましたら、幸いです。